# Is there a way to create dynamic Panel using a model

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Is there a way to create dynamic Panels in Primefaces without using jstl or ui:repeat to loop over ?

I want to create it using a model, like how a menu model can be created.

something like the below,

```
<p:panel value="#{bean.list}" var="b">

</p:panel>
```

Comment: If i understand your question you want to generate a number of panel depending of a parameter(it can be 5, or more ) ?!?

Comment: you can make your code inside a `dataGrid` and use it to generate your panel

Comment: @YagamiLight . Yes

Comment: I ve told you to create a `dataGrid` and put your panel inside it and you generate your panel

Comment: I want to create the panels dynamically inside the p:dashboard, and so i dont want it inside a dataGrid.